# jquery call back in django template

Tags: django

In my django template I'm using $.ajax jquery method where url is pointing to one of my django view. Now how can i use render_to_response in this django view?

```
def document_status(request):
    if request.method == u'GET':        
        GET = request.GET
        if GET.has_key(u'doc_type') and GET.has_key(u'iqama_no'):
            pass
    json_response = simplejson.dumps({'res':True})
    #return HttpResponse(json_response, mimetype='application/json')
    return render_to_response('tracking/index.html' )
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: The above view is called via jquery $.ajax method. Now i want to redirect to index template, but the above code is not redirecting to index.html template. Is there any way to redirect to specific django template on callback in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX isn't used for redirection, it's used to asynchronously get data from the server.

But if you really want to redirect, instead of rendering a template (which will not work), return a `HttpResponse` containing the URL you want to redirect to, and in the AJAX call `success` function use the returned data to redirect from javascript.

So the javascipt code would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<your url>",
    data: <whatever data you want to send>,
    success: function(new_url){
        window.location = new_url;
    }
});
```

And the Django handler:

```
def document_status(request):
    # Do stuff...
    return "http://url/you/wand/to/redirect/to"
```

**Edit**

To answer the question in the comment, this is one way to do it:

First the html template for page A:

```
<form action="http://url/of/page/B">
    <select name="value" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="1">First option</option>
        <option value="2">Second option</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The view code for page A shouldn't have to change, so the view for page B:

```
def page_b_view(request):
    value = request.GET.get('value', '0')  # '0' is default value if not found
    if value = '1':
        # Add some context variables here
    elif value == '2':
        # Add some other context variables here
    return render_to_template(...)
```

This should hopefully give you hints for how to do it, or what to search for.

Comment: But i want to pass some template variables to index.html. The value of these variables will depends on the data which will be send via ajax. How can i achive this?

Comment: @Asif You can not add or change context variables through AJAX! Either you reload the page, or you redirect to another page.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this? i tried $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url test %}') but it is resulting in same template, means two templates in one page

Comment: @Asif See my answer for how to redirect. For reloading the current page see for example [this](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html) page.

Comment: Suppose i have dropdown field in PAGE A. Now on select event i want to redirect to PAGE B with some django context variables. The value of these context variable is depends on the selected value of PAGE A dropdown field. How can i implement this in django?